# Responsive images srcset, always serves highest resolution image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have been reading up on `srcset` and responsive images the last few days and experimented with it, I'm not quite sure I understand how a image is chosen.

I'm running on a 2160x1440 monitor, with a css pixel ratio of 1.5. Given the following example I was expecting the browser to display image_1.5x.jpg.

```
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image_1.5x.jpg 1.5x, image_2x.jpg 2x">
```

But I always get the one with highest pixel ratio (2x in this case). If I would enter 30x, that image would be served. Isn't the one that matches my monitors pixel ratio the most appropriate one?

If I emulate a slow network connection the default image.jpg gets served.

I'm running Chrome, and I realize that depending on what browser is running, different results may occur.

Comment: Support for `srcset` is not even that good, so I wouldn't rely on it. Also, I'm not sure if you can do halves...i.e. 1.5, because the examples I'm seeing show whole numbers only.

Comment: @slime srcset="image_1.5x.jpg 2x, image_2x.jpg 30x" still makes the 30x one display, so halves should not be a problem.

Comment: Ignore my comment about halves, that doesn't seem to matter, but if I had to guess I would say the 1.5 in the file name of the first one might be throwing everything off. You should probably leave the period for file extensions only.

Comment: @slime Seems as you're right. Thank you:)

Comment: If your devicePixelRatio is 1.5, you should see the 1.5x image loaded. Do you have a test case I can look at? Also - are you using any srcset polyfills?

Comment: @slime periods in the file name shouldn't make any difference. If they do, that's a browser bug.